# How to use a foreach-loop in Scala that mutates an object?

Tags: scala, jdbc, foreach, prepared-statement

I use Scala and JDBC, now I want to reuse an `PreparedStatement` to do a multi-insert. I want to use a foreach-loop over an array, but I can't get it right with Scala.

```
val stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertStatement)

// wrong Scala
items.foreach(item : MyItem =>
    stmt.setInt(1, item.id)
    stmt.setInt(2, item.value)
    stmt.executeUpdate()
    )
```

`items` is an array containing multiple `MyItem`.

How can I write this foreach-loop in Scala and reuse the `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: Could it just be that you need to use curly braces (`items foreach { ... }`) in order to get the multiple-line block to execute properly?  If not, please explain **why** it is wrong (e.g. give the compiler error message, or the incorrect behaviour that results).

Comment: @Andrzej: I have tried to put `{` and `}` in a few places but I can't get it compiling with any combination. The error in this case is `Error raised is : ')' expected but '(' found.` *at* `stmt.setInt↓(1, item.id)`

Comment: @Jones it looks like it is a curly brace issue; I've added an answer demonstrating this.  If you're still seeing problems then it's probably based on a logical error somewhere else, rather than the way Scala handles foreach loops.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the curly brace syntax at this position, I used them inside the parentheses.

Comment: The signature of `foreach` is `def foreach (f: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit` so it's expecting a function. You can write an anonymous function (closure) of any length using curly brackets. The compiler allows you to omit the parentheses if you have a single argument that is a closure. Also, you can omit the curly brackets (but keep the parentheses) if your closure is a single statement.

Comment: @Luigi: The thing that confuses me was that it's not a strict function, since I have `MyItem` as argument, but using `PreparedStatement` object inside... Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use curly braces for the argument to `foreach` if you want it to be interpreted as a multi-statement *block* (which you do).

Asides from that, what you're doing looks fine.  Here's a REPL session where I'm mutating an object in a foreach block in a similar way (using a StringBuilder for simplicity):

```
scala> val sb = new java.lang.StringBuilder
sb: java.lang.StringBuilder =

scala> val items = List("tinker", "tailor", "soldier", "spy")
items: List[java.lang.String] = List(tinker, tailor, soldier, spy)

scala> items.foreach { item =>
     |   sb.append(item)
     |   sb.append("; ")
     |   println(sb)
     | }
tinker;
tinker; tailor;
tinker; tailor; soldier;
tinker; tailor; soldier; spy;
```

(And using parentheses for the foreach block leads to the error `<console>:3: error: ')' expected but '.' found.`)

Comment: @biesczadka I'm not sure I follow: If you want to return it from a function, then just make sure it's the return value of your function!  Either way, that has **nothing** to do with this question or my answer, so if you still have issues you should post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 11):

A small point, but Andrzej's answer can be cleaned up by using infix notation more liberally:

```
val sb = new java.lang.StringBuilder

val items = List("tinker", "tailor", "soldier", "spy")

items foreach { item =>
  sb append item
  sb append "; "
  println(sb)
}
```

Generally, it's considered more idiomatic to use the infix form for collection operations such as `map`, `flatMap`, `foreach` and `filter`

Comment: This comment surprises me. Here's the discussion in the style guide: http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/method_invocation/arity1/index.html and http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/method_invocation/arity1/higher_order_functions.html The rule seems to be that infix notation should be *only* used for immutable functions, and preferably with higher order methods such as `map`. Since `append` is a mutation, the style guide says don't use infix.

Comment: The style guide is just that, a *guide*. It contains guidelines (not rules) and it's not absolute gospel.  You will find differences of opinion on some of the suggestions there, including this one :)

Comment: As an obvious counter-example to the rule, the assignment method, `=`, is side-effecting, but is always used in infix notation.